# How to set all the programmatically added ImageViews to nil?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Every time you click on the create button 4 rows of images are created. I'm using this technique for the game mastermind. When you click on the clear button every imageview has to be set to nil, but now only the last created 4 imageviews are set to nil. Any help would be appreciated!

```
- (IBAction)create {

    _imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(134, y, 30, 30)];
    _imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, y, 30, 30)];
    _imgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(206, y, 30, 30)];
    _imgView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(241, y, 30, 30)];

    _imgView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[textfield_code objectAtIndex:0]];
    _imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[textfield_code objectAtIndex:1]];
    _imgView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[textfield_code objectAtIndex:2]];
    _imgView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[textfield_code objectAtIndex:3]];

    [self.view addSubview:_imgView1];
    [self.view addSubview:_imgView2];
    [self.view addSubview:_imgView3];
    [self.view addSubview:_imgView4];


    y += 41;
}

- (IBAction)clear {
    [_imgView1 setImage:nil];
    [_imgView2 setImage:nil];
    [_imgView3 setImage:nil];
    [_imgView4 setImage:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enumerate the view's subviews

```
for(UIImageView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]) {
       [v setImage:nil];
    }
}
```

BUT this is 'dangerous' as it removes ANY image view there is. **it'd be better to use tags** too.

#### e.g.

define it as `#define MyTag 100`

and when will creating `v.tag = MyTag`

and then in the loop check it  `if(v.tag == MyTag)`